# PHP: Create variables by accessing online database using PDOs

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, pdo

I'm trying to create some variables for the database name, user, and password. I've only done this with localhost and looking for a solution on accessing a website database that's online.

This is what I have so far using PDO. Any help would be appreciated

```
function connect()
{

try 
{
    // Connect to database
    $conn = new \PDO('mysql:host=www.yourwebsite.com;
                            database=databasename;
                            user=username;
                            password=password');

    // Turn on Error Mode for PDO and PDO Exception
    $conn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    return $conn;
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation for [`PDO::__construct()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) and [PDO_MYSQL DSN](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).

The DSN specifies (amongst other things) the hostname and database, using `host` and `dbname` elements respectively; whereas authentication credentials are supplied as subsequent arguments to the `PDO` class constructor:

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$database = 'my_database';
$username = 'hiebert';
$password = 'r34lly_53cUr3';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
```

Comment: Thanks, but further more how would you assign the username and password from the database into varables? Or would that be it? I'm somewhat new to php.

Comment: @nick.hiebert: I had understood your question to mean that you were attempting to *connect to the database*, for which PHP will need to know valid authentication credentials for MySQL before it is able to connect.  If you have a table of users (and passwords) in your database, and want to do something with them, then that must be for something specific to your application (rather than connecting to MySQL): you will need to provide more detail.